# R ftable percentage

Tags: r, percentage

```
year <- c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002)
county <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
score <- c("High","High","Low","Low","Low","High","High","High","Low")
df <- data.frame(year,county,score)
tb <- ftable(year ~ county + score, data=df)
#             year 2000 2001 2002
#county score                    
#A      High          1    0    1
#       Low           0    1    0
#B      High          1    0    1
#       Low           0    1    0
#C      High          0    1    0
#       Low           1    0    1
```

How can I add column percentages next to each numbers?

Comment: What language and what sort of denominator? Grand total as denominator or group sub totals?

Comment: I prefer group sub total. If possible, could you show both?  What language? I use R.

Comment: I am not stick to base R. tidyverse is fine.

Comment: Group subtotal by year, by county, or by score?

Comment: Can you show how your expected output would look for this data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can get a response to questions about the goals by putting up an answer to our guesses.

I would not use the ftable object but rather start with the dataframe, and since I'm thinking you need the columns to be years we will put that second in the array we build with the table command:

```
 tbl <- with(df, table(county,year, score))
 tbl
#------------------------
, , score = High

      year
county 2000 2001 2002
     A    1    0    1
     B    1    0    1
     C    0    1    0

, , score = Low

      year
county 2000 2001 2002
     A    0    1    0
     B    0    1    0
     C    1    0    1
```

Now we can form column percents by multiplying the `prop.table` result (with the margin being 2 for the years columns) by 100 and rounding:

```
(ptbl <- round( 100* prop.table(tbl, 2) ) )
, , score = High

      year
county 2000 2001 2002
     A   33    0   33
     B   33    0   33
     C    0   33    0

, , score = Low

      year
county 2000 2001 2002
     A    0   33    0
     B    0   33    0
     C   33    0   33
```

And only now do we apply the magic of `ftable and then use "[" to interleave he results:

```
(final <- cbind( ftable(tbl, col.vars="year"), ftable(ptbl,col.vars="year"))[ , c(1,4,2,5,3,6)] )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1   33    0    0    1   33
[2,]    0    0    1   33    0    0
[3,]    1   33    0    0    1   33
[4,]    0    0    1   33    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1   33    0    0
[6,]    1   33    0    0    1   33
```

(I would advise a more complex example since the one supplied has the same proportions regardless of which margin is being used as the denominator.)